# mysql sort table names by foreign key dependencies in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to find out all tables of one database sorted by foreign key constraint. Actually I am copying one database tables to other database. So I get all tables of one database by

```
 SHOW TABLES FROM mydatabase
```

And then loop through the result of this database and create/insert table/records in other database. This works fine if there is no foreign key constraints. But if there are foreign key constraints, then it generates `mysql 150 error`. Like if above query has returned tables in following orders

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alerts
    [1] => CompanyGroup
    [2] => company
)
```

Now in this order if `CompanyGroup` has foreign key constraint to `company` table then my following foreach loop

```
 foreach($tables as $table) {
     $tableinfo = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbConnection1, "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table"));
    mysqli_query($dbConnection2, " $tableinfo[1] ")
 }
```

will throw the error as in second iteration, while creating `CompanyGroup` table it will reference to `company` table that doesn't exits in database.

So I would like to know how can I sort tables with foreign key dependenceis. I actually want to get output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alerts
    [1] => company
    [2] => CompanyGroup
)
```

This is a general script so I cannot put manual conditions. This script should run on any database. Database can have 200 to 400 tables with million of records. Please guide.

Comment: You can disable key comprobation with **SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;**

Comment: But I need to copy exact schema and structure.

Comment: Yes, you could copy schema and attributes, after you disable foreign_key_check (this makes mysql not check for foreign keys constraints) and copy data and finally enable foreign_key_check

Comment: Can you please more elaborate it? Preferably in answer?

Comment: Exactly as @Edu wrote: disable foreign key checks before the copy and enable it after the copy is completed. This  does not affect either the schema or the data.

Comment: Hi, for cloning schema http://www.matteomattei.com/how-to-clone-mysql-database-schema-in-php/